# Null Pointer Error in Split function

Tags: java, arrays, string, split, nullpointerexception

I was trying to split a String into a String array using the split function but received the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at wdtbam.main(Main.java:16)
```

I was solving this problem at [Codechef](https://www.codechef.com/problems/WDTBAM).
My goal was to split the String into indexes of an array wherever a space was encountered and later parse that into Long type.

Here's my code

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
class wdtbam
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(br);
        int t =sc.nextInt();
        for(int i=1;i<=t;i++)
        {
            int n =sc.nextInt();
            String a =br.readLine();
            String b =br.readLine();
            String c = br.readLine();
            String cx[]= c.split(" ");  //the problem
            long d []=new long[1234];
            int y=0;
            for(int j=0;j<=n;j++)
            {
                d[j]=Long.parseLong(cx[j]);
            }
            for(int k=0;k<n;k++)
            {
                if(a.charAt(k)==b.charAt(k))
                {
                    y++;
                }
            }
            System.out.println(d[y]);
        }
    }
}
```

I have been encountering this problem since long and it would be very appcreciable if someone could help me out.

EDIT:

I removed BufferedReader from my code and instead used only Scanner.
I also tried to directly input the numbers into an array instead of inputing a string and later parsing it to an long array.

Here's my new code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
class wdtbam
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int t =sc.nextInt();
        for(int i=1;i<=t;i++)
        {
            int n =sc.nextInt();
            String a =sc.nextLine();
            String b =sc.nextLine();
            long d []=new long[1234];
            int y=0;
            for(int j=0;j<=n;j++)
            {
                d[j]=sc.nextInt();
            }
            for(int k=0;k<n;k++)
            {
                if(a.charAt(k)==b.charAt(k))
                {
                    y++;
                }
            }
            System.out.println(d[y]);
        }
    }
}
```

I am still getting an error. IDK why. 
Please help I am really frustrated with JAVA right now.

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
    at wdtbam.main(Main.java:18)
```

BTW here's the problem I was trying to solve : [Codechef](https://www.codechef.com/problems/WDTBAM)

Comment: I don't see the need for the BufferedReader... Just use `Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in)` and `sc.nextLine()`

Comment: The problem is that you are reading too many lines of input. `br.readLine();` returns null when the stream has ended

Comment: This exception is strange here since `br` is reading `System.in` which should be opened (I don't see any closing statements). So `readLine` couldn't return `null` which could cause NPE.

Comment: I see that the question is marked duplicate, I tried to understand the [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) but couldn't successfully find an implementation relevant to my case. I mean how will I implement that solution in my particular case (Please Tell).

Comment: I tried what all is mentioned by @cricket_007 but it returned the same error.